# T-Sql: Case Expression with Mutliple condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Currently i have this statement and is bringing me correct results

```
select 
    case column1
        when 'G07' then 'G15'
        when 'G09' then 'G15'
        when 'G15' then 'G15'
    end
    as Code 
from tableX
```

The problem with the above is that i have bunch of cases to write for each column, so I'm after something more compact like the following but unfortunately do not compile :

```
select 
    case column1
        when 'G07','G09','G15' then 'G15'
    end
    as agente   
from tableX
```

Any thought? Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using an alternate form of `case`:

```
select 
    case 
        when column1 IN('G07','G09','G15') then 'G15'
    end
    as agente   
from tableX
```